# Functions with a flexible list of ordered/unordered and labeled/unlabeled inputs in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, argument-passing, variadic-functions

A lot of MATLAB functions have an input structure such as:

```
output = function MyFun(a,b,c,'-setting1',s1,'-setting2',s2,'-setting3',s3)
```

I am wondering how I should implement this kind of functionality in my own functions. To be precise, I would like to find out how I can create a function such that:

1. The function has a variable number of inputs `N + M`
2. The first `N` inputs are **ordered and unlabeled**. In the example above, `N = 3`. The first input is always `a`, second input is always `b`, third input is always `c`. The function input is variable in that users do not necessarily need to send `b`, `c`; when they do not then these can take on default (hardcoded) values. As far as I know, this type of functionality is generally handled via `varargin.`
3. The remaining `M` inputs are **unordered, but labeled**. In the example above, `M = 3`, the variables are s1,s2,s3 and their labels are `setting1`,`setting2` and `setting3` respectively, I would like for users to be able to specify these variables in whatever order they want. If users choose not to specify one of these inputs (i.e. `setting1`), then I would like my function to assign default values for `s1.`

One example of such a function is the [dlmwrite](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html) function.

Ideally, I am looking for an approach that is typically used by MATLAB developers so that my code is easy to understand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`InputParser`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputparserclass.html) class addresses all of these issues. You can specify any number of:

1. Required parameters (ordered, unlabeled)
2. Optional parameters (ordered, unlabeled)
3. String parameter-value pairs in any order (unordered, labeled)

---

A very clear [tutorial with examples](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/parse-function-inputs.html) is provided by MathWorks. For a function defined as `function printPhoto(filename,varargin)`, the example boils down to the following.

Create the `inputParser`:

```
p = inputParser;
```

Specify defaults and define validation criteria:

```
defaultFinish = 'glossy';
validFinishes = {'glossy','matte'};
checkFinish = @(x) any(validatestring(x,validFinishes));

defaultColor = 'RGB';
validColors = {'RGB','CMYK'};
checkColor = @(x) any(validatestring(x,validColors));

defaultWidth = 6;
defaultHeight = 4;
```

Define required/optional/parameter input names, set their default values and validation functions:

```
addRequired(p,'filename',@ischar);
addOptional(p,'finish',defaultFinish,checkFinish);
addOptional(p,'color',defaultColor,checkColor);
addParameter(p,'width',defaultWidth,@isnumeric);
addParameter(p,'height',defaultHeight,@isnumeric);
```

Parse the inputs into a struct:

```
parse(p,filename,varargin{:});
```

Then you have the input arguments and their values in `p.Results`.

The `InputParser` class is used throughout newer MathWorks functions, so don't be afraid to use it yourself!