# how to append args

Tags: matlab, variadic-functions

I have a function :

```
function  launchMe(values)

launch('arg1',values.value1,'arg2',values.value2)
end
```

I would like to create a function that can add to the basic launch other arguments

```
function myFunc(values,..)
end
```

and this function will call the launch with default args and if additional args=> it added them to the launch function

```
launchMe(values) => launch('arg1',values.value1,'arg2',values.value2)
launchMe(values,'toto') => launch('arg1',values.value1,'arg2',values.value2,'toto')
launchMe(values,'arg3','tata') => launch('arg1',values.value1,'arg2',values.value2,'arg3','tata')
```

Is there a specific MATLAB command to add args and values ?

Comment: See the Q&A reference above, but for more sophisticated argument handling with the `inputParser`, see also [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20337956/2778484).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`varargin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html) and [`nargin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nargin.html) to handle variable number of input argument. please read the documentation and see the examples there.

Comment: could you give more precise answer please ?

Comment: @lola have you give it a try? have you tried writing code with `varargin`? have you tried debugging this code? If you have specific question - please feel free to post them as new questions.

Comment: I've tried :  function  launchMe(values,varargin)
    if nargin >1
    launch('arg1',values.value1,'arg2',values.value2,varargin{:}) end
    end

Comment: @lola - you tell me. what are the values of `varargin` and `nargin` when you run your function? have you tried debugging it?