# optional input arguments with dynamic variable numbering matlab

Tags: matlab, function, dynamic, for-loop, variadic-functions

I'm trying to write a function in MATLAB, having optional input arguments and the function is called in for loop, I want two things:

- firstly, optional input arguments i.e no need of sequence of inputs
- secondly, whenever the function is calling, it numbers the variable
  name so that no conflict is left, it is required as no output is deserved.

**My function:**

```
function mYfunc(a,b,c,d,e,f)
var1= 'some string';
% for numbering, may be use of eval(['var' num2str(1)]) but how the function call is identified, 
% i.e in same loop function calls again, then iteration is identified

if nargin >= 3
 %some operation
end

if nargin >= 4
  %some operation
end
if nargin >= 5
   %some operation
end
if nargin >= 6
   %some operation
end
end
```

**The for loop:**

```
for i=1:3
mYfunc(a,b,c,d,e,f); %first call, var1 is expected
mYfunc(a,b,e,f); %second call, var2 is expected
mYfunc(c,d,e,f); %third call, var3 is expected
mYfunc(a,b,c,d); %fourth call, var4 is expected
mYfunc(c); % fifth call, var5 is expected
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to use `varargin` along with your if statement to assign inputs to certain variable names (e.g. `if nargin==4, b=varargin{2}; end` or whatever you want).

There is a slight learning curve, but for the most versatile solution I also suggest you look into using MATLAB's [`inputParser`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputparserclass.html), which gives you all the flexibility you need. It also allows you to specify inputs by a name (string).  See also [this description of `inputParser`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20337956/2778484).

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your question, but probably the `inputname` function can help you. It tells you the name of a certain argument when the function is called.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputname.html