# Giving default values to only some function variables in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, argument-passing

I made a Matlab function

```
function foo(argone, argtwo)
```

The begining of the function allow to have default choices for those variables if the function is called only with one or even zero arguments

```
function foo(argone, argtwo)
if(~exist('argone','var'))
    argone = defaultargone;
end
if(~exist('argtwo', 'var'))
    argtwo = defaultargtwo;
end
... % Rest of the code
```

We can call the function as

```
foo()                   % Default values are assigned to argone and argtwo
foo(myargone)           % Default value given to argtwo
foo(myargone, myargtwo) % No default values are used
```

But how to be able to give default value to argone only?

If function is called with

```
foo(~, myargtwo)
```

no default values are used; argone get the null value (that is not the default value)

Thank you for your help

Comment: You might find the [`inputParser`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20337956/2778484) class useful. It's easier than it looks, and it will actually make your life much easier. Adopt it and never look back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternate way would be to include the option for handling an empty input:

```
function foo(argone, argtwo)
if ~exist('argone','var')||isempty(argone)
    argone = defaultargone;
end
if ~exist('argtwo','var')||isempty(argtwo)
    argtwo = defaultargtwo;
end
```

Then any of these should work:

```
foo()
foo([],[]) 
foo(argone)
foo([], argtwo)
```

Answer (score 0):

The language itself does not support such inputs. A common workaround  uses parameter value pairs.

Usange would be

```
foo('myargone',1, 'myargtwo',2)
foo('myargtwo',3)
foo('myargone',4)
```

In your function, you have to use varargin and the [input parser](http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2012/02/13/parsing-inputs/)